# Can't seem to get BXSlider working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use BXSlider and can't seem to get it working

The code. The linked JS/CSS are downloaded from the site and have the correct path.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
  <script src="../js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
  <link href="../js/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="../js/script.js"></script>

<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="../Images/Welcome/0008.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="../Images/Welcome/0025.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="../Images/Welcome/IMG_0061.jpg" /></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Everything seems good to me, please check the path of js and css files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if you have proper path of JS and CSS file. Also follow the proper sequence of code.
1. Include files need for initialization.
2. HTML code.
3. Controller/ Script for modification or targeting.
See below code:

in **< head >** tag

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in **< body >** tag

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

before **< /body >** tag

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Oh should of mentioned that I have already done that (forgot to add in code snippet).

And the script is in another file

Comment: Your script is in another file and that might be the issue. Make sure to load it at bottom once `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Still can't seem to get it working. I have checked the paths and they are fine also.